# Linux pattern kill command

Tags: linux

I have a process running as

```
php -q 1.php TEST 22
php -q 1.php MAIN 22
php -q 1.php TEST 222
php -q 1.php MAIN 222
php -q 2.php TEST 22
php -q 2.php MAIN 22
```

i need a linux command which kill just 1st two process only.

Comment: Learn about [pgrep(1)](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_pgrep.htm) and `pkill`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pkill -f` to kill a process by name with arguments, **it accepts regex as well**:

```
pkill -f 'php -q 1.php TEST 22'
```

Using regex to identify top 2 processes:

```
pkill -f 'php -q 1\.php.*22'
```

Comment: How to use regex here ?

Comment: I will give you an example as soon as I get back to my computer.

Comment: Updated an example with regex.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried head ?

```
ps -aef|grep 'php *'|grep -v grep |head -n 2|awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9
```

Comment: where exactly is it matching "22" and "1.php"

Comment: ps -aef|grep 'php -q 1.php TEST 22'|grep -v grep |head -n 1|awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9